# How do I use the DocuSign Node.js SDK in a Next.JS web application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docusignapi

I am working on an existing Next.js web application, and I would like to add the DocuSign Node.JS SDK to use the JWT Auth and generate a token for my front-end application. The Next.JS app is hosted on Vercel, which can run serverless functions.

I am having trouble building the Node.JS endpoint to obtain the JWT Auth token to call the esignatures API. Does anyone know how to integrate the JWT Auth workflow into a Next.JS/React.JS application with serverless functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocuSign Node.js SDK is currently designed for server side use only.

To use the DocuSign API from the client (browser):

- Only the Implicit grant flow can be used from the browser due to restrictions in the OAuth standard.
- If the user of your application does not have a DocuSign account (eg the user will be a signer), then you have two options:

  - using JWT grant auth on a backend server, acquire an access token for a "system user" such "hr@example.com". Use this access token to create an envelope and the signing ceremony (for embedded signing). Or use the access token as needed by your app. If the app includes a (non-DocuSign) login, then you can pass the access token to the browser and make calls from it.
  - use the [PowerForms API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BKfyDSMoSE) if it meets your needs
- To make API calls from the client, you will need to build a CORS forwarding proxy since DocuSign doesn't yet support CORS natively. And to make the API calls themselves, call the API directly since no SDK is available at this time.

Comment: Thanks Larry. I actually read your blog post on building a React app with DocuSign from 2018 that explained the steps to create a proxy. I think I will use the PowerForms API as it does most of what I'm hoping to accomplish with my app.